# Get rid of extra sep in the paste function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get rid of the extra `sep` in the `paste` function in R. 
It looks easy but I cannot find a non-hacky way to fix it. Assume `l1-l3` are lists

```
l1 = list(a=1)
l2 = list(b=2)
l3 = list(c=3)
l4 = list(l1,l2=l2,l3=l3)
```

note that the first element of `l4` is not named. Now I want to add a constant to the names like below:

```
names(l4 ) = paste('Name',names(l4),sep = '.')
```

Here is the output:

```
 names(l4)
[1] "Name."   "Name.l2" "Name.l3"
```

How can I get rid of the `.` in the first output (`Name.`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can ue `trimws` (from `R 3.6.0` - can specify `whitespace` with custom character)

```
trimws(paste('Name',names(l4),sep = '.'), whitespace = "\\.")
#[1] "Name"    "Name.l2" "Name.l3"
```

---

Or with `sub` to match the `.` (`.` is a metacharacter for any character, so we escape `\\` to get the literal meaning) at the end (`$`) of the string and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\.$", "", paste('Name',names(l4),sep = '.'))
```

---

If the `.` is already there in the `names` at the end, we can use an index option

```
ifelse(nzchar(names(l4)), paste("Name", names(l4), sep="."), "Name")
#[1] "Name"     "Name.l2." "Name.l3"
```

Comment: Thanks but the second solution does not work for l4 = list(l1, l2. = l2, l3 = l3)

Comment: @MyQ It is giving the same output in my case though.  If you have already assigned it and then tried on `sub`, it would be a different input though

Comment: @MyQ `sub("\\.$", "", paste('Name',names(l4),sep = '.'))#
[1] "Name"    "Name.l2" "Name.l3"` where `names(l4)#
[1] ""    "l2." "l3"`

Comment: That is right but the actual dot in `l2` is not removed. Then the true name of the variable is now manipulated

Comment: The expected output is `"Name"    "Name.l2." "Name.l3" `